# How Difficult/Project Size/Time to wrap an Angular/Firebase WebApp in PhoneGap

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, cordova

How difficult is it to wrap an existing web app for the sole purpose of acquiring push notification capabilities??

I have a fairly complex working webapp with a proprietary ui that utilizes custom CSS.  It is written in Angular and uses Firebase and a couple of proprietary backend servers ( Python Tornado and Node ).  The apps runs reasonably well as is however the UI is not as snappy as I would like and most important is the lack of push notifications.    I would really like to understand from someone who knows phonegap well how difficult is this to do?  Are the many changes required of my web app to access a push api?>